# Utilizing recursion to compute a series

Tags: java, recursion

I must be failing to wrap my head around the concept of trying to store a value in a recursive method.  Solving this using iteration would take seconds, but I am struggling with the recursive call.  Basically I am trying to solve: 1/1 + 1/2 + 1/3 ...

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);    

    System.out.print("Enter in the end number for the sequence: ");
    int endpoint = input.nextInt();

    System.out.println("The value of the sequence is : " + calcSequence(endpoint));

    }

    public static double calcSequence (int index){

        if (index == 0)
            return 0;
        else
            return (1/index) + calcSequence(index - 1);
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to add some explicit type conversions.  Your `1/index` is being performed as integer division, and your call is losing all its precision.  Simply changing this to `1.0/index` (or `1d/index` to indicate that the `1` should be used as a `double`) should get you what you're looking for.

Comment: I knew it was something stupid.  I broke out the pen and paper and it seemed logically sound.